# Money-making super-power?

Tags: super-powers

I'm trying to come up with the super-power that would be best for making money. I define "best" as:

- **Simple**: as easy to describe as possible
- **Legal**: should be possible to explain it legally. Example: making gold out of thin air is great, but then authorities may ask - from where did the income arrive?
- **Sustainable**: it should work on the long run. Example: if I just create money / other assets out of nothing - then that asset will decline in price due to market saturation
- **Scalable**: such super-power should be good in making \$1 or \$100 or \$100.000.000; this does not mean all three cases must be instantaneous - it's reasonable if \$100 takes longer than \$1.

You ideas?

Comment: This seems pretty opinion-based. Super-intelligence so they can consistently invent popular things, or the ability to see the future and make money on investments, or super-persuasion to get people to sign over their valuables, or super-geology to see oil and gold underground, or... any other equally valid option.

Comment: With making money do you mean EARNING or PRODUCING?

Comment: hypnosis a la hypno-toad from futurama, get yourself broadcasted once and create an unstoppable social media following then collect advertiser dollars

Answer (score 5):

**Divination!**

If your guy can use tarot cards, oija board, consult the bones..... it enables to play the stock market.

You can invest tiny amounts or invest large amounts. 
Knowledge is scalable without any limit since it can be applied in radically different ways. Invest in the stock market ooooor if you know next year Detroit will raise in value, buy lots of land for peanuts now.

Divination also can be used with an Inventor buddy!
Go to big pharma and get a deal for a new medicine.
Call Elon Musk and tell them if you add tweaks here and there your car is more efficient.

Not all deals require money.

And if you are feeling daring...
Call CIA or any other 3 letters agency and tell them you can give them info. Offer a few freebies as proff.

In the words of Ravenclaw:
*Wit beyond measure, is a man's greatest treasure!"*

Comment: Even merely seeing a minute or two into the future allows one to gamble for fortunes. Just don't get too greedy at any one casino, and be sure to deliberately lose now and then to conceal your perfect ability to know when/where to bet big.

Comment: Totally agree. Te main flaw here is Human discipline to know when to loose. Otherwise you will get your knuckles crushed in some backroom and banned from life in Las Vegas.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi there was a movie called "Next" where Nicolas Cage played the role of a person who could see 5 minutes (IIRC) in the future. He earned money in casinos that way by staying under the radar and only winning small enough sums to avoid suspicion before cashing out.

Comment: Using predictive abilities to get rich off the stock market was going to be my suggestion. +1.

Comment: @VLAZ There shouldn't be any reason to only win small amounts - just be sure to win some lose some, while your *net* winnings can be enormous. Sometimes a whale gets lucky and wins big on a day of gambling. Just lose almost as often as you win and nobody is the wiser as you were just lucky in coming out way ahead at the end of the day.

Answer (score 2):

## Controlled reincarnation

Just wait until some billionaire wants to have a heir, then incarnate as that heir.

If you are born poor you really have to fight your way into wealth, specially in poor countries. But if you are born rich? You have to fail extremely hard to fall out of wealth.

As as a rich kid, at school age you might already be able to invest in funds with good returns.

Comment: It's not very fast, though. You might have to wait at least 18 years to get some free money (you might have a tight allowance - stuff is *provided* but you're not given that much to spend) and likely around 20-21, so you can finish a university, get a degree and be put in at an executive job within your parent's company.

Comment: oh. thats fair i guess.

Comment: You left out the grisly detail that you need to commit suicide for this plan to work.

Comment: @NuclearWang how so? You can just die rich of old age and then reincarnate with the password to your bank accounts.

Comment: Why heir? Kill billionaire and reincarnate as him. This seems to work for a number of supernatural creatures.

Comment: @Renan How do you die rich the first time? Barring suicide, I'm going to have to wait several decades (hopefully) before I can reincarnate into money, and then a couple more before I can actually spend it on something fun. This works fine if you're the patient type, but I don't want to wait 50+ years before this superpower earns me a dime.

Comment: @NuclearWang making money takes time. Only suckers go for quick money, which is why *get rich quick* schemes are so profitable for con-artists.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe Scrooge McDuck can literally smell money, which can be useful for mining precious metals. He's also pretty lucky (he would disagree and say it's all hard work, but he's probably comparing himself to Gladstone).

The ability to dive and swim in money would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

**Super-genius.**

Create tech, sell off your "B" tier tech, keep the "A" tier tech for yourself.  Use the profits from the "B" tier to fund more research, lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: This is exactly what Syndrome does in *The Incredibles*. "How do you think I got rich? I created weapons, and now I have a weapon only *I* can defeat [...] Of course, I saved the best inventions for myself."

Comment: @F1Krazy Lex Luthor  since crisis on infinite earths.

Comment: Also the source of income for the Fantastic Four.

Answer (score 1):

### Mind control

Find a rich person.  Command the rich person to give you money.  Now you are a rich person.

Unless you are actually farming, quarrying, mining or some other primary industry, all wealth is ultimately created by shuffling resources around and exchanging them from each other.  Even divination will only allow you to acquire wealth by out-knowing other people who are also chasing after the same profits.  By far the easiest way of acquiring wealth is to take it from someone who already has it.

This checks the simplicity, scalability and sustainability boxes straightforwardly.  As far as legality goes, you only need to look at something like Fyre Festival or the latest imploded tech unicorn to see how completely plausible it is that large numbers of rich people would be persuaded to invest huge sums in whatever the hell you like.

Comment: When you think about it, this is pretty much how the average Hollywood self-help "guru" works, except without needing quite so much charisma.

Answer (score 0):

a simple street trick power. the ability to levitate items. that could give you an audience, and sure there are going to be naysayers, but that is only going to prove that it isn't actually a "superpower" and that its just a neat trick this guy learned, and he wants to show off his hard work, show he's homeless with no job, and make them dolla' dolla' bills yo. and if someone dares try to check, just tell them that it's just fake. maybe have an actual extremely tiny string attached, even if you don't need it.

Comment: I'm not sure street performers win THAT much money over all.

Answer (score 0):

**Being able to see just a few hours into the future - OR - able to rewind time while keeping your own memory (as in "[Groundhog Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day_(film))" but at will & over a shorter time).**

Then 'gamble', easy money & as much or little as you want (depending on how much attention you're willing to risk drawing), be careful not to burn too many bookies too badly or the same one too often if you don't want trouble, loose once in a while too, that will help you look normal.

Just a few minutes *might* suffice rather than a whole hour or so, but that would rule out 'betting' on anything that take more than that to play out, that' going to restrict your options & make it harder to spread it arou8nd in ways to make your luck seem less unusual.

You could have great career as an NSA analyst with this power too.

Answer (score 0):

## Healing

If you can cure incurable diseases or heal serious injuries, you can practically name your price, as this is an incredible boon for the very wealthy (whether that wealth is legitimate or... not). Think "highly skilled medical specialist" (a profession that already is known for being lucrative) turned up to 11. Or you can do minor stuff for an affordable price and still make a mint in volume. See Correia's [Grimnoir Chronicles](https://grimnoirchronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Grimnoir_Chronicles_Wiki) for an example.

(Incidentally, I'm also using *exactly* this as a background element in a story I'm currently writing... one of the main characters can use 'biological magic', which allowed her to make a pile of money some years before my story happens, such that at the time of the story, she is living entirely off of investment returns.)

The catch is that it's (probably) obvious that your character *has* this power. Your question isn't clear whether or not that is acceptable...

Answer (score 0):

**Immortality.**

1. Find a reliable savings account with a high compound interest rate.
2. Open an account with some seed money - say, $1,000.
3. Wait. As long as the country's inflation rate remains below your account's interest rate, you will be making money without lifting a finger. If inflation ever does get too high, withdraw your money, find a country with a lower inflation rate, and repeat Step 1.
4. ???
5. Profit (literally).